# Selenium. Найти элемент по изменяющемуся id, match, несколько элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

В Вконтакте есть "написать сообщение":

`<div class="im_editable im-chat-input--text _im_text" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" id="im_editable450262838" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"></div>`

im-chat-input--text - попадается два раза, тот, который интересует - второй

1. Такое написание будет правильно?

`driver.find_element_by_class_name('im-chat-input--text[1]')`

2. Как найти элемент с ID `im_editable450262838`
   по маске типа `im_editable*`?

`driver.find_element_by_id('im-chat-input--text*')`

3. Можно ли в Selenium искать через MATCH, чтобы просто вставить кусок кода, по примеру, и потом ввести значения:

`driver.find_MATCH ('class ="im_editable im-chat-input--t')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Правильно будет так:

   `el = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('im-chat-input--text')[1]`

---

2. Поиск по маске `im_editable*`:

   `el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'im_editable')]")`

---

3. Поиск по куску кода

   Любой самый сложный элемент состоит из атрибутов и их значений. Используйте `xpath` для поиска.

   В общем случае:

   `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//elementType[@firstAttributeType = 'firstAttributeValue'][@secondAttributeType='secondAttributeValue'][@thirdAttributeType='thirdAttributeValue']....");`

   Например:

   `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='im_editable'][@class='im-chat-input--t']");`

   Подробнее про `xpath` можно почитать, например, в [Мануал по XPath](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PdfKMDfoqFIlF4tN1jKrOf1iZ1rqESy2xVMIj3uuV3g/pub)